# How to see workflow app permissions?

Tags: 2013, workflow, app-permissions

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2014/11/20/workflow-app-permissions/) which shows how to go into Site Features and turn on Workflow app permissions, then go to Site settings > Site app permissions and copy the workflow app identifier GUID.

Then I go to the "hidden" **~/layouts/15/appinv.aspx** page and paste/lookup the GUID. All of this is working. But when I get there the `App's Permission Request XML` field is blank. I paste in the recommend permission XML to give my workflow FullControl

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

And click create. That seems to work and it give my workflow the correct permissions.

But I don't see any way to check which permissions have been granted. I tried going back to the hidden page, but the XML was empty again.

How can future me figure out what permissions were given to which app? Is there another hidden page? Is there some query?

I'm only a site collection owner, so I don't have access to central admin.

Comment: Future you here, did you manage to find a way to list the permissions?

Answer (score -2):

Sure. You can see which apps were given permissions by going to the **Site app permissions** page. Site Settings > Site app permissions (under Users and Permissions).

Comment: That page only lists the name of the app and the app identifier. It doesn't show the actual permissions assigned to that app.